# Reconnect Xcode project to existing repository after name change

Tags: xcode, repository

I've changed a Xcode project name and in the process also changed the project's root directory's name. What happened as a result is that it broke off the existing repository, so I can't commit from Xcode. Is there a way to reconnect the files in their new folder to the repository, so that I have all the file changes history?

Comment: I am not sure this is the best solution...  
What I am doing is this:  
1. Clean the solution folder (with all subdirectories) from all ‘.svn’ file (this is for Subversion)  
2. Connect clean solution to the repository.  
If somebody knows the better solution, I would happy learn also.

Comment: I'm using Git. Won't deleting the .git folder remove the entire history of my changes?

Comment: In any case, the history of changes is on server

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change your project name:

- Open a project
- Select Project Navigator
- Highlight project name
- Single click on project name
- Then write your new name

first take a copy from your old project and paste it in another place and folllow my

this is my personal project

[image: this is my personal project]

after you change the name you should have message like this, after that the app should be run normally

[image: after you change the name you should have massege like this]

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3

Comment: I've already changed my project's name, but I also changed the root directory's name from the old name to the new name, so for example file1.h that was under "\oldname\file1.h" is now under "\newname\file1.h" and so Xcode repository can't locate it.

Comment: Sorry for late >>> :)

Comment: what happen did you fix it? i did upload my answer.